# Where and how to place apple-touch-icon in TYPO3 app

Tags: typo3-9.x

I'm getting the following error in the backend:

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1518472189: The requested page does not exist | 
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Http\PageNotFoundException thrown in file /var/www/vhosts/my-doma.in/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/ErrorController.php in line 80.
Requested URL: https://my-doma.in/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png
```

To place an apple icon one apparently should add:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/path/to/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

somewhere, as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21144916/4120196

But given a TYPO3 (v9.5) application - Where and how should I to add this?

Comment: It can be in the page's template, extension's template, or even generated by TypoScript. We can not know that as you didn't give us any details. Please fix your question or it will be closed and/or downvoated.

Comment: What can you not know? I'm the one that doesn't know stuff here, that's why I'm asking :D One good solution is enough for me I don't need to know all of them. But I need a real example or a link to one. I don't know how to generate this with TypoScript.

Comment: You mention some TS part, which even didn't show us :) I'd like to know a way to read data from any computer in the net, but I don't sorry ;)

Comment: I guess you were distracted from my main question by my `shortcutIcon` sentence - I removed it now for a clearer question.

Comment: What I meant was that you mentioned that you used some TypoScript which causes the problem, but didn't show us the code, without which it was hard to know what's wrong. As I assume you found the solution, so that's good for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way after stumbling on the [headerData](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Setup/Page/Index.html#headerdata-array) property - added this to my TypoScript root template:

```
page.headerData {
       1 = TEXT
       1.value = <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="fileadmin/path_to_icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
}
```

And I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63558477/4120196) when it comes to Android as well.
My android browser seemed to be happy already with the apple icon though.